# Finite intersection property

Tags: general-topology

My teacher said that the collection of sets

$\left \{(0,1),(0,\frac{1}{2}),(0,\frac{1}{3}),...  \right \}$ has finite intersection property because

1. $(0,a_1)\cap(0,a_2)\cap(0,a_3)\ldots\cap(0,a_m)=(0,b)$, where $b=\min\left \{a_1,a_2,a_3...a_m\right \}>0$
2. $\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)=\emptyset$.

My question is why is the second condition important? Isn't the first condition enough?

Comment: Yes the first condition is enough. The second condition is important since it shows that $(0,1)$ is therefore not compact.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your teacher gave it to you in order to introduce you to countable intersections, and to show you what holds for finite intersection(that is, the sets are non-empty), might not hold for infinite intersection, although it does not show that $(0,1)$ is not compact as they are not closed subsets.